# Failed to populate DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am population DataGridView from DataTable, but getting following error:

> At least one of the DataGridView
>   control's columns has no cell template

```
private void PopulateGridView(DataTable dt)
        {

            if (dt != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    //Declare the bound field and allocate memory for the bound field.
                    DataGridViewColumn datacolumn = new DataGridViewColumn();

                    //Initalize the DataField value.
                    datacolumn.DataPropertyName = col.ColumnName;

                    datacolumn.Name = col.ColumnName;

                    //Initialize the HeaderText field value.
                    datacolumn.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;


                    //Add the newly created bound field to the GridView.
                    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(datacolumn); // ** Error **
            }

                //Initialize the DataSource
                this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
```

Comment: Whats wrong with simply doing "this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because you are adding the base column type `DataGridViewColumn` which has no cell template assigned. If the DataGridView was to try and assign a new cell for this column it would not know what to do.

You can either choose to define the column type, or to set the column's cell template to a cell.

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
datagridview1.Columns.Add(col);
```

or

```
DataGridViewColumn col= new DataGridViewColumn();
DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

col.CellTemplate = cell;
datagridview1.Columns.Add(col);
```

There are several available column types.

**However** what you probably want to do is let the columns get autogenerated. With the DataGridView property AutoGenerate columns set to `true` (the default) the columns are created when you assign the datasource.

Adding columns programatically is often useful (for example adding a check box column to allow row selection) but in this case you shouldn't need to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Like [ASPMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574142/aspmapper) said in the comment below the original question, just set it. You don't even have to clear your columns before hand:

```
private void PopulateGridView(DataTable dt)
{
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
  // notice if your DataTable is null, it simply clears the DataGridView control
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your code crashes because `DataGridViewColumn` does not provide a cell template ...

maybe you want to use one of those? (instead of the base `DataGridViewColumn`)

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
DataGridViewImageColumn
DataGridViewLinkColumn
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```

on the other hand ... the DataGridView is capable of auto-creating the columns at runtime when a new datasource is provided ...

Answer (score 1):

```
private void PopulateGridView(DataTable dt)
{


    if (dt != null)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
}
}
```

Is doing the job for me.